# Merging Two Forall and Sum Constraints

Tags: minizinc

I'm looking at a way to merge these two constraints together, and feel there is a way to utilise an IF statement to merge them together. My attempt is below but I couldn't seem to get the constraints to perform correctly. Can someone help as I believe there is a simple way to join them and thus make the model perform more efficiently.

---

```
%Constraint 4 - Coaches must have 3 or less Juniors

constraint forall (coach in Coaches where coach != Unallocated) 
                    (sum(coachee in Coachees where   Coachee_Grade[coachee]=Junior) (Matched_Coach[coachee,coach]=1) <= 3);
                                                                                                  
%Constraint 5 - Coaches must have 4 or less Seniors

constraint forall (coach in Coaches where coach != Unallocated) 
                    (sum(coachee in Coachees where Coachee_Grade[coachee]=Senior) (Matched_Coach[coachee,coach]=1) <= 4);
```

---

```
%Constraint 4 + Constraint 5 - Coaches must have 4 or less Seniors, 3 or less Juniors     
      
constraint forall (coachee in Coachees, coach in Coaches where coach != Unallocated) 
                    (if Coachee_Grade[coachee]=Junior then (Matched_Coach[coachee,coach]=1) <= 3) 
               else (Matched_Coach[coachee,coach]=1) <= 4) endif);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to explicitly record for every coach if they are coaching students from a junior or senior level. This would simplify the sum constraint and possibly allows you to specify a search strategy that fixes this first, which might be helpful.

```
array[COACHES] of var bool: coaches_juniors;
% Ensure coaches that teach senior will never teach juniors
constraint forall(coach in COACHES where not coaches_juniors[coach], coachee in Coachees where Coachee_Grade[coachee]=Junior) (
  not Matched_Coach[coachee,coach]
)

% Constrain coaches to teach at most 4 students or 3 when junior
constraint forall (coach in Coaches where coach != Unallocated) (
  sum(coachee in Coachees)(Matched_Coach[coachee,coach]=1) + coaches_juniors[coach] <= 4
);
```

This should capture the constraints mentioned.

---

Furthermore you might think about the view point of your model. You have chosen a Boolean matrix for your variables, but in CP it is often worthwhile to describe your model at a higher level. (This very much looks like an integer programming model). You might instead want to try describing it using:

- A variable set for every coach that contains the trainees. (Potentially arrays of 4 instead of sets, if you need more control and know how to eliminate the symmetries).
- Or an integer variable for every student to assign a coach.

It sounds like a LCG solver like Chuffed or OR-Tools would work well with your model, so using this higher level view would probably get you better results.

Note that MiniZinc is build to translate high-level models to whichever solver is targeted. Generally it is best to use high-level MiniZinc and let the solver library choose the encoding of the problem that is best.